# Отбивается ли тире пробелами, когда стоит между римскими цифрами?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, пробелы, даты, цифры

В "Правилах русской орфографии и пунктуации" (1956) сказано следующее (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/158-tire)):

> § 178. Тире ставится между двумя словами для обозначения пределов
> пространственных, временных или количественных (в этом случае тире
> заменяет по смыслу слова «от... до»), например:
> Перелеты СССР –
> Америка.  Рукописи XI – XIV вв.

Но ведь мы знаем, что единственный случай, когда тире не отбивается пробелами, – позиция между цифрами (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=286781)), то есть правильно: "рукописи 11—14 вв.", а римские цифры — тоже цифры, следовательно, и тут надо так же: "рукописи XI—XIV вв.". Значит, имеет место противоречие между правилами? Вероятно, может, стоит считать вышеупомянутую норму в параграфе 178 устаревшей? Тем не менее "Грамота.ру" настаивает на старом и без объяснений советует отбивать тире между римскими цифрами (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=306803)):

**Вопрос № 306803**

> Скажите пожалуйста как писать интервал римскими цифрами - через пробел
> или нет

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Следует писать через тире с пробелами: *в XIX — XXI веках*.

Как быть, какому правилу следовать и как не рехнуться от таких несостыковок в нормах русского языка?

Comment: *То есть правильно: "рукописи 11—14 вв.* Столетия принято записывать римскими цифрами.

Comment: Это понятно, вопрос именно в пробелах.

Comment: Приветствую! Поправьте ещё вот здесь. (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F) Я могу **рехнуться** и забыть, какое мое имя настоящее и под каким я должен вам звонить, а под каким ― писать стихи. [Евгений Евтушенко. «Волчий паспорт» (1999)]

Comment: @ShiKomarishe А ведь хороший вопрос, *Shi*! Как же ж я его не отметила? Исправляюсь. Принимай плюсище.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, благодарю)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В спорных случаях каждая редакция использует собственный унифицированный свод типографских правил. К примеру, [вот эта](http://esmira.net/uroki/vtoroj-urok.html) пишет между римскими цифрами короткое тире без пробелов.
Но с пробелами, на мой взгляд, выходит и эстетичнее, и читабельнее (поскольку сами римские цифры состоят преимущественно из прямых чёрточек, тире без пробелов сливается с цифрами и "на глаз" определяется не моментально).

**Дополнено:**

Обратите внимание, что и у [Розенталя](https://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=95#pp95), и у [Лопатина](https://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg19.php) тире между цифрами отбивается пробелами. А вот у [Мильчина](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091464.html#id-6%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-615%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) в справочнике, посвящённом именно современной типографике, указано, что тире в подобных случаях пробелами не отбивается.