# Летом—осенью / летом — осенью

Tags: пунктуация, тире, пробелы

Как правильно?

> Летом—осенью 2023-го не было тыквенного супа вообще.

> Летом — осенью 2023-го не было тыквенного супа вообще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

• Есть правило Розенталя.

> **§ 8.** [Соединительное тире](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=95#pp95)
> **1.** Тире ставится между двумя или несколькими словами для обозначения пределов (‘в значении от … до’): <...>
> 2) временных: *Крестовые походы **XI — XIII веков**, Репертуар театра на **январь — март***...

• Есть примеры.

*Один из моих собеседников, кадровый офицер МВД, **летом — осенью 1994-го** воевал против Дудаева* (Владимир Воронов. Восстановительный откат).
*Советская власть натурализовалась здесь с приключениями: **летом — осенью 1918-го** красные были вынуждены отбивать захваченную белочехами... Казань приступом...* (Л. А. Данилкин. Ленин: Пантократор солнечных пылинок).

• Есть решение.
Оно не орфографическое, а пунктуационное. Ставим тире с пробелами.

*Летом **—** осенью 2023-го не было тыквенного супа вообще.*

Comment: А с чего пробелы возле тире, где римские цифры? Тире без пробелов между ними ставится.

Comment: Тут вот какое *интересное* дело. У Лопатина временное тире между римскими цифрами тоже отбивается пробелами. *...культура конского каштана в северо-западных парках явление не **XVIII — XIX веков**, а более позднее...* (http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108#pp108) И есть дискуссия по этому поводу на нашем сайте: "Отбивается ли тире пробелами, когда стоит между римскими цифрами?"

Comment: @Максим https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470948/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8

Comment: Это какие-то реформы в русском языке начинаются?

Answer (score 2):

**Лето-осень**

```
    Посвящается Лео, узнавателю русского языка


    Лето-осень, осень-лето —
    Это что, не разберешь,
    В ласке солнечного света
    Так осенний день хорош!

    И зеленая поляна
    С желтым кленом хороша,
    Нас природа обманула,
    Зелень с золотом смешав.
```

27 октября 2023 года

Comment: Не, если _с лета по осень_, то тире с пробнлами.

Comment: Стихотворение "Лето-осень". Щемящий душу отзвук летних дней, Этап осенних перемен в природе... Ютится Лето в зелени полей. Янтарным блеском Осень хороводит!    Поэзия, музыка, живопись... 
 https://yandex.ru/search/?text=лето-осень&clid=2270455&banerid=0701004840%3ASW-c2cd38eacda5&win=532&lr=213

Comment: Надо этот вопрос сделать конкурсным... Через два дня.  Приз от меня  100 баллов. Иди даже двести. Кто больше?